# How to pass multiple values one by one for a Parameter in an SQL Query and union the results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, union

I have an SQL Statement which accepts a parameter `@EndDate as DateTime`. I want to be able to pass several values for `@EndDate` one by one and then `Union` the results of all the Queries. I have tried using CTE for this but it is of no use. I want to pass several Dates for `@EndDate`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My Query is:

```
DECLARE @EndDate as DateTime
SET @EndDate = '2018/02/25'

SELECT  
CONVERT(VARCHAR, @EndDate, 101)  [R_Date]
,[Name]     
[Type] 
FROM [dbo].[S_Table]
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: How you are passing several values, in a sequence or random values please add some sample data

Comment: Might be storing several @EndDate into one `temp table` and then `join` the same with your `[dbo].[S_Table]` and perform rest of the tasks.

Comment: @B House currently I m passing one date at a time. But  I want be able pass the value in a sequence may be from a date range. How do u suggest achieving this?

Comment: Not clear. Show sample data please.

Comment: @TheDProgrammer if you are looking to pass in sequence a while loop will do this, try creating `@startdate and @enddate` , and what you are trying to acheive, ? 'Insert or update or select ?

Comment: @BHouse I have tried while loop but it is yielding me separate results in query window. I want the results to be UNION ALL. I am running this on a SELECT Statement.

Comment: @NEER here is the sample data when @EndDate = '2018/02/24'
`R_Date Name Type
2/24/2018 A Monthly
2/24/2018 A Daily`
when @EndDate = '2018/02/25'
`R_Date Name Type
2/25/2018 TEST_1 Monthly
2/25/2018 TEST_2 Monthly
2/25/2018 TEST_3 Daily
2/25/2018 TEST_4 Weekly
2/25/2018 TEST_5 Monthly
2/25/2018 TEST_6 Monthly
2/25/2018 TEST_7 Monthly
2/25/2018 TEST_8 Monthly
2/25/2018 TEST_9 Monthly
2/25/2018 TEST_10 Monthly`

Comment: @TheDProgrammer if you have date ranges, this can be achieved effectively using cte with recursion

Comment: @TheDProgrammer There is 2 rows at `2/24/2018` and There 10 rows at `2/25/2018` How do you select?

Comment: @NEER the [Name] Column has a case statement and there is a WHERE Clause too at the end.

Comment: @BHouse please help me write the CTE. My SQL Statement is in my Question.

Comment: @TheDProgrammer do u filter variable in where clause ?

Comment: @BHouse yes I am filtering

Comment: Please edit your query and add exact filter on the variable

Comment: @BHouse that will complicate my question. I want to keep it simple. Please suggest a method to pass multiple values to EndDate Parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This is Sample query how u can loop through multiple dates. A while loop should select all rows into one table, do not need to perform `union all`

```
   DECLARE @table TABLE (
    day INT
    ,Month INT
    ,DATE DATE
    )
DECLARE @startdate DATE = '2018/02/25'
DECLARE @enddate DATE = cast(getdate() AS DATE)

WHILE @startdate <= @enddate
BEGIN
    SELECT @startdate = dateadd(dd, 1, @startdate)

    INSERT @table (
        day
        ,Month
        ,DATE
        )
    SELECT day(@startdate)
        ,MONTH(@startdate)
        ,@startdate
END

SELECT *
FROM @table;
```

In your logic for passing multiple values into query , you can store result set into temporal table, which holds looped records

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (
    [R_Date] DATE
    ,Name VARCHAR(155)
    ,Value VARCHAR(155)
    )
DECLARE @enddate DATE = '2018/02/25'
DECLARE @enddate1 DATE = cast(getdate() AS DATE)

WHILE @enddate <= @enddate1
BEGIN
    SELECT @enddate = dateadd(dd, 1, @enddate)

    INSERT @table (
        R_Date
        ,Name
        ,Value
        )
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, @EndDate, 101) [R_Date]
        ,[Name] [Type]
    FROM [dbo].[S_Table]
    WHERE DATE = @enddate
        -------More filters
END

SELECT *
FROM @table;
```